# Access this.$root in Vue.js 3 setup()

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

In Vue 2, you can access `this.$root` inside the `created` hook. In Vue 3, everything that would have gone inside the `created` hook now goes in `setup()`.

In `setup()` we don't have access to `this`, so, how can we access anything on the root instance?

Say, I set a property on the root instance:

```js
const app = createApp(App).mount('#app');

app.$appName = 'Vue3';
```

I can access `this` from `mounted()` with `this.$root.$appName`, how can I do this in `setup()`?

---

**UPDATE**

I can access it if I `import` it:

```js
import app from '@/main';
...
setup() {
    console.log(app.$appName) // Vue3
```

But, this is a hassle if I have to do this for every file.

---

**UPDATE 2**

Another workaround is to use `provide()` inside `App.vue` and then `inject()` in any other components:

```js
setup() {
    provide('$appName', 'Vue3')
```

```js
setup() {
    inject('$appName') // Vue3
```

Comment: did you `console.log(this)` to see whats going on?

Comment: `this` is `undefined` inside `setup()`

Comment: well i guess you cannot access it then `When setup is executed, the component instance has not been created yet`

Comment: The root instance would have to exist before the component though

Comment: I can't find anything in the docs about it so maybe it can't be done

Comment: hmm.. but you have access to the props. Maybe you pass your root instance as a prop down to the child?

Comment: I'm not sure how I could do that. `setup` takes two arguments of `props` and `context` so maybe there's a way to add it through the apps config. Problem is, the docs for `app.config` aren't for single file components so I can't get them to work either

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It seems you need [provide / inject](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-provide-inject.html). In your `App.vue`:

```
import { provide } from 'vue';

export default {
  setup() {
    provide('appName', 'vue3')
  }
}
```

Or `provide` it with your `app`:

```
const app = createApp(App);
app.mount('#app');

app.provide('appName', 'Vue3');
```

---

And then in any child component where you want to access this variable, `inject` it:

```
import { inject } from 'vue'

export default {
  setup() {
    const appName = inject('appName');
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing if you are looking for a constant, you can also just define it somewhere `export const appName = 'Vue3'`, and then wherever you want to use it, you can `import { appName } from 'constant.js'`.

Comment: Your second solution:
`const app = createApp(App);
app.mount('#app');
app.provide('appName', 'Vue3');
`
didn't work for me. `app.provide('appName', 'Vue3');` should be before `app.mount('#app');`

Answer (score 27):

You could  define [global property](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/application-config.html#globalproperties) in vue 3 :

```
app.config.globalProperties.appName= 'vue3'
```

With `setup` (composition api) you could use [getcurrentinstance](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/composition-api.html#getcurrentinstance) to get access to that property:

```
import { getCurrentInstance } from 'vue'
...
setup() {
    const app= getCurrentInstance()
    console.log(app.appContext.config.globalProperties.appName)
```

Since you're still able to use the options api you could simply do :

```
mounted(){
   console.log(this.appName) 
}
```

Comment: `getCurrentInstance()` isn't documented on the page you provided?

Comment: It was documented, but It's now available in the core module and used internally by the framework and It's no longer available as exposed api, I'll try to find another solution

Answer (score 5):

If all you want is to replace `{{ appName }}` in any any template with `'Vue 3'` (string), without having to import anything, the cleanest way would be using [config.globalProperties](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/application-config.html#globalproperties), as suggested by other answers:

```
const app = createApp(App).mount('#app');
app.config.globalProperties.appName = 'Vue 3'
```

---

However, you ***should try not to overuse*** this pattern. It goes against the reusability and modularization principles which drove the development of Composition API.

The main reason why you should avoid polluting `globalProperties` is because it serves as pollution field across Vue3 apps, so many plugin devs might decide to provide their plugin instance using it. (Obviously, nobody will ever name a plugin `appName`, so you run no risk in this particular case).

The recommended alternative to globalization is exporting a `useStuff()` function.
In your case:

```
export function useAppName () { return 'Vue 3' }
// or even:
export const useAppName = () => 'Vue 3'
```

In any component:

```
import { useAppName } from '@/path/to/function'

setup () {
   const appName = useAppName()
   return {
     appName // make it available in template and hooks
   }
}
```

The advantages:

- it uses the Composition API naming convention
- when sharing something more complex than a primitive (could be a module, a set of functions, a service, etc...) ***all types*** are inferred, out of the box.  This is particularly useful in `setup()` functions.
- you only expose and scope your `stuff` where you need it exposed, not in every single component of your app. Another advantage is: if you only need it in `setup()` function, you don't have to expose it to template or hooks.

---

Example usage with a random (but real) plugin:
Create a plugin file (i.e:  `/plugins/gsap.ts`):

```
import gsap from 'gsap'
import ScrollToPlugin from 'gsap/ScrollToPlugin'

// configure the plugin globally
gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollToPlugin)

export function useGsap () {
  return gsap
}
```

In any component:

```
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
import { useGsap } from '@/plugins/gsap'

export defineComponent({
  setup () {
    const gsap = useGsap()
      // gsap here is typed correctly (if the plugin has typings)
      // no need for casting
    return { 
      gsap  // optionally provide it to hooks and template
    }       // if needed outside setup()
  }
})
```

Comment: Yeah it seems like the Vue team really didn't want people having global properties like with Vue 2. I even tried doing `setup() { getCurrentInstance().hello = 'abc'} and the object is frozen (unmodifiable), so I can't add that property

Answer (score 2):

For anyone wondering how they can simply access `this` inside `setup()`, one way is to set `this` to a memoized variable in the `created()` hook and use `nextTick()` to access it:

```
const app = createApp(App);

app.config.globalProperties.$appName = 'Hello!';
```

```
<script>
import { nextTick } from 'vue';

let self;

export default {
    name: 'HelloWorld',

    setup() {
        nextTick(() => console.log(self.$appName)); // 'Hello!'
    },

    created() {
        self = this;
    },
};
</script>
```

[@Psidom's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64040666/12701949) is better practice in my opinion, but, this is just another way.