# where to create a websocket component in vue application

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I need to create a websocket component that my UI will use. I only want to establish a connection when the user is logged in, and I want to issue a terminate command when the user logs out of the application. But I am unsure how I can create such a utility so that I can call it from various components. To do this, I am checking the Vuex store, but I'm not clear where I should put my utility.

My project:

```
- main.js
- App.vue
- components/
  helloWorld.vue
```

How could I place my code

```
const WSS = new WebSocket(WEBSOCKET_BASE_URL);
```

so I can call something like `WSS.terminate()`, or `WSS.send()`

Answer (score 0):

You can create it in `App.vue` or `helloWorld.vue`.

You can place your code in `created` hook. See the example below.

```
created: function() {
   const wss = new WebSocket("url");
}
```

You can read the [tutorial](https://tutorialedge.net/javascript/vuejs/vuejs-websocket-tutorial/).

Comment: If I put this in App.vue, would I be able to call wss.terminate() from a child component, such as helloworld.vue ?

Comment: @dataviews, if you have  the setup in App.vue and you want to terminate from child component, then the child component can emit a custom event and App.vue will listen for the emitted event and will call wss.terminate(). But I think it would be easier if you have the entire websocket code in child component. That way you don't need to emit events.

Comment: Could I just call this.$root.wss() from the child component, or is this not safe?

Comment: You could use `provide/inject` or emitting a custom event in the child component that calls a method, that closes the WebSocket.

https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject.html

For further information refer to this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64040286/access-this-root-in-vue-js-3-setup