# this.$root.$on alternative for Vue3?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to migrate an old Vue2 project to Vue3 and I found this deprecated syntax in one of the components.

```
if (!this.eventsOnLotsenFinder) {
      this.$root.$on('openLotsenFinder', () => {
        window.removeEventListener('keyup', this.onWindowKeyUp);
      });
```

it gives me this error on hover

> Property '$on' does not exist on type 'ComponentPublicInstance<{}... >

I haven't found an alternative for this in the migration guide.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64042256/8172857

Comment: or using the event bus https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63471824/vue-js-3-event-bus/64019074#64019074